# Comparing two dates in String format

Tags: java, date, date-comparison

I am trying to compare two dates in integers (e.g., `10-05-2018`). Format of those two days is the same and the preferred solution is without the `Date` type. My ideas were to write the dates backwards and compare them as integers, which is not working as a found a counterexample: 10,09,2018 and 09,09,2018. Any other ideas? Thanks!

```
for (int i=0; i<date.length(); i++) {
    date3 = date.charAt(i) + datum1;
    date4 = date2.charAt(i) + date2;

}

if (datum3.compareTo(datum4)>0) {
    return 1;
}
if ((datum3.compareTo(datum4)<0)) {
    return -1;

}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: *"My ideas were to write the dates backwards and compare them as integers..."* Or indeed, as strings. *"...which is not working as a found a counterexample..."* Yes, it works (if by "backwards" you mean year-month-day and you use full years and two-digit months and days). We can't help you understand why a "counterexample" didn't seem to work if you don't show us the counterexample.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what about 10,09,2018 and 09,09,2018?

Comment: Those clearly can't be compared as strings or as numbers, as the most significant part (year) is at the end. Again, if you use `year<delim>month<delim>day` and write a 4-digit year and 2-digit months and days, you can do a string comparison. If you want to use integers, `yyyymmdd` as a number will work provided there are no leading zeros. I can't tell from your examples whether you're used to U.S. mm-dd-yyyy format or the more rational dd-mm-yyyy format. (I kid, I'm an American [well, dual]. ;-) ) But `20180909` and `20180910` can reliably be compared (whether those are strings or numbers).

Comment: This is why ISO-8601 is the *one, true date format*. :)

Comment: We’d love to help. We can do that if you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and in addition to the counterexample also specify how it fail, that is, which result you got instead of hte expected one. Also, there is a reopen vote already, and more will follow if you provide what I ask.

Comment: If you have reversed your counterexample strings into `8102.90.01` and `8102.90.90` I think you can see why they compare in the wrong order. Just guessing, though, in lack of a minimal, complete and verifiable example. I’d love to be able to run your code to see and understand what goes wrong. That requires a complete example.

Comment: “… without the Date type”, that is an excellent idea since the `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated. I do warmly recommend that you use the `LocalDate` type and other classes from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

We use integers in the format yyyymmdd

We can use a regular int type, sort works, uses less space than Date, readable

But what’s missing is date arithmetic operations which will require conversions

Also consider LocalDate ... newer java data type from Joda

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't want to use `java.util.Date` or its replacement [java.time.LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), probably because it is an assignment.

Comparing those number can be done by converting each component to `int`, and then using `Integer.compare` on each component, from the year to day:

In pseudo code, this would mean:

```
For each component in [Year, Month, Day]:
  n = compare(date1[component], date2[component])
  if n != 0 then 
    return n
return 0 // all component are equals.
```

There are several way to process to get the components into an array of int, with Year = 0, Month = 1 and Day = 2 representing the index of each component into said array.

You can convert the whole `String` into a `int[]` array. If you know the format, using a `Pattern` (see note) (such as `Pattern.compile("^(?<DAY>\d+)-(?<MONTH>\d+-(?<YEAR>\d+)$")`) is probably the easiest to validate the `String` follow some set format. It also permits you to extract the component (using `matcher.group("DAY")` and so on).

Comparing the `String` as a number can be done in two ways:

- Have fun with digits.
- Use `Integer.parseInt(String)`.

Since you should probably validate the range of component (each month between 1 and 12, days between 1 and 31 [or depending on the month], ...), converting to int would be the easiest.

**Note:** for an assignment, not using `java.util.Date` but allowing `Pattern` would be probably counterproductive.